# remove all special characters in zapier

Tags: zapier

I have several variables coming in to zapier that i'd like to remove all special characters (only English letters and numbers remaining). How do I do that in JavaScript and what do I enter in the "Code" box of my zap? I am not a coder, as you can tell.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not a coder, using the [Zapier Formatter](https://zapier.com/help/formatter/) may be an easier option.
You can choose the [Replace feature](https://zapier.com/help/formatter/#using-replace), state the input you would like to work on, and then choose what text to replace with another text.

For example, you can choose a special character that Zapier supports like [:newline:] which is a line break, and then place in nothing for the "Replace" option. This would remove all line breaks from the input.

Hope this helps!

[image: textformatter on Zapier]

Comment: Thanks - yes, I've used to replace feature on zapier, but looking for something more efficient since I'd rather not have to create a separate step to replace each individual character that I don't want. Is there a way to replace multiple chararcters at once using the replace feature? I know that it only replaces the first occurrence of a character as well, rather than all of them.

Comment: Yes, if you have 5 special characters you would like to remove, you will have to have 5 replace steps in your single Zapier flow. The formatter should replace all occurrences though - like in the image I posted, it is getting rid of 2 occurrences.
I think it's fair though that you stick to this method instead of coding, as you have not provided any coding examples yourself. Users at Stackoverflow would be happy to debug any issues, but it is not a place to expect code to be created from scratch.

Comment: Just re-read my comment, and I must apologize for not answering one of your questions.

>Is there a way to replace multiple chararcters at once using the replace feature?

I tried several ways to try this using the replace feature, but I couldn't find a way to do it in 1 go.